# DJANGO static images dont show in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to use static images in my template using the DJANGO framework, but the images don't display on my page.

I have followed  the manuals completely.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here the code :

html :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
div class="portfolio-item">
<a href="#"><img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="{% static portfolio2.jpg %}"></a>
</div>
```

settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','static_dirs'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','media')
MEDIA_URL = ('/media/')
```

urls.py

```
+
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: quotes `'portfolio2.jpg'` before file

```
<a href="#"><img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="{% static 'portfolio2.jpg' %}"></a>
```

Comment: @ChrisPapas, If the solution worked for you, please vote up and select the answer or else if any problem let me know. Thanks for all the cooperation.

Comment: @ChrisPapas, Feel privileged to help you out.